# materialize css slider not working, showing grey background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

hey guys am using materialize css for my site. when i insert the code for the slider it only shows a grey background. here is my code:

```
<div class="slider">
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
    <div class="caption center-align">
      <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
    <div class="caption left-align">
      <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
    <div class="caption right-align">
      <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
    <div class="caption center-align">
      <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the slider by calling slider()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Plugin initialization
    $('.slider').slider();
})
```

You're also going to need materialize.js

Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytqL0tz3/1/).

Comment: I have a seperate JS( in which i initialize the slider) file which I included in my index.html, but it is not showing the images on the server.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".slider").slider();
  $(".dropdown1").dropdown();
});`

Answer (score 0):

First you need materialize.js plugin. Then you must plug below javascript code into your .html file or .js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.slider').slider();
})
```